# How to write an in-memory java class to a .class file?

Tags: java, classloader

In my application, I am compiling some groovy files to `Class<?>` using [`groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html). These classes are saved in a `HashMap` and used later.

Since this compilation happens at startup time, the startup takes longer than desired.

Is there a way to dump the generated `Class<?>` objects to some `.class` files, and next time directly load the classes from a jar?

So I am looking for a way to write `.class` files from in memory `Class<?>` objects

Comment: `Class`es are no objects, i still dont get why so many people dont know this fundamental difference. If you want to create bytecode _(read : **.class-files**)_ you need to compile sourcecode which *templates* object *instances*. I really think you should pause your current task / project and go back to java programming basics first, obviously there are large knowledge gaps which need to be filled first ... otherwise you might end up with little real knowledge and a lot of false assumptions ..... just a suggestion

Comment: thanks for your comment and suggestion

Comment: @specializt The point is clear. But intuitively, one (even I, with >15 years of Java experience) might be tempted to think that *somehow* everything that has been loaded from a `.class` file must be "in memory" in the JVM (and somehow be associated with a `Class` object). Of course, it would be naive to think that something like this could be achieved by just "serializing a `Class` object" or so. But I could imagine that there is some way of "hooking" into the `GroovyClassLoader` (which is a `URLClassLoader`), and monitor the loaded data (i.e. the `byte[]`) to store it in a `.class` file...

Comment: probably, yes .... but that'd be highly experimental and most likely unsupported / untested. If you start hooking into classloaders you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @specializt I'm not so sure, maybe there is a viable solution. @ weima Can you extend the question with some *minimal* code snippet that shows how the classes are loaded and stored? This may make clearer where and how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little late to this question, but I found a way recently.
Checking code inside I know internally the `GroovyClassLoader` uses a class called `CompilationUnit`. You can use it like this

```
CompilationUnit cu = new CompilationUnit()
cu.addSource(compilationUnitName,srcCode)
cu.compile()
cu.getClasses() //This returns a list of `GroovyClass`es, they contain the 
//name and the bytecode (byte[]) of the generated classes.
```

You can then save the bytes in a file with .class extension and voilá. You can zip them in a `.jar` file, or on you can load such classes using `GroovyClassLoader` method `defineClass`